# MySQL: Self Join issue - Unknown Column in Field List

Tags: mysql

Hello I keep getting this error when trying to self join in MySQL. I have done this in the past in different way using Post Gres SQL, however I am new to MySQL. Essentially I have a group of columns that I want to aggregate using SUM, and then I want to join it with other columns (within the same table after I have done the aggregation. I keep getting the following error

'Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'm' in 'field list'

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT
    e.IncidentDate,
    e.City,
    e.Tract,
    SUM(e.InvolvedPedesrian) as InvolvedPedesrian,
    SUM(e.InvolvedCyclist) as InvolvedCyclist,
    SUM(e.InvolvedMotorist) as InvolvedMotorist,
    SUM(e.TotalInjuries) as TotalInjures,
    SUM(e.TotalDeaths) as TotalDeaths,
    SUM(e.TotalCasualties) as TotalCasualties,
    SUM(e.TotalCyclistInjuries) as TotalCyclistInjuries,
    SUM(e.TotalCyclistCasualties) as TotalCyclistCasualties,
    SUM(e.TotalPedestrianInjuries) as TotalPedestrianInjuries,
    SUM(e.TotalPedestrianDeaths) as TotalPedestrianDeaths,
    SUM(e.TotalPedestrianCasualties) as TotalPedestrianCasualties,
    m.B01003_001, m.B02001_002, m.B02001_003, m.B02001_004, 
    m.B02001_005,
    m.B02001_006, m.B02001_007, m.B02001_008, m.B03002_012, 
    m.B01001_002, m.B01001_026,
    m.B01002_001, m.B01002_002, m.B01002_003, m.B20002_001, 
    m.B20002_002, m.B20002_003,
    m.B08135_001, m.B08006_001, m.B08006_002, m.B08006_003, 
    m.B08006_004, m.B08006_008,
    m.B08006_014, m.B08006_015, m.B08006_016, m.B08006_018, 
    m.B08006_019, m.B08006_020, m.B08006_021,
    m.B08006_025, m.B08006_031, m.B08006_032, m.B08006_033, 
    m.B08006_035, m.B08006_036, m.B08006_037,
    m.B08006_038, m.B08006_042, m.B08006_048, m.B08006_049, 
    m.B08006_050, m.B08121_001, m.B08121_002,
    m.B08121_003, m.B08121_004, m.B08121_005, m.B08121_006, 
    m.B09008_002, m.B09008_004, m.B09008_005,
    m.B09010_002, m.B09010_003, m.B09010_004, m.B09010_005, 
    m.B09010_006, m.B09010_007, m.B09019_002,
    m,B09019_003, m.B09019_005, m.B09019_006, m.B09019_007, 
    m.B09019_008, m.B09019_024, m.B09019_038,
    m.B15003_002, m.B15003_016, m.B15003_017, m.B15003_018, 
    m.B15003_020, m.B15003_022, m.B15003_023,
    m.B15003_025, m.B16001_002, m.B23025_004, m.B23025_005, 
    m.B17020_002, m.B08201_002, m.B19013_001,
    m.B19013A_001, m.B19013B_001
FROM 
    master  e
        INNER JOIN 
    master m on m.Tract  = e.Tract 
GROUP BY e.IncidentDate, e.City, e.Tract
Limit 5;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 m,B09019_003
```

You need a period there instead of comma.

Comment: Wow... You have really good eyes.

Comment: @PM77-1 or he used CTRL+F and entered `m.` cause he assumed it :-)

Comment: @dognose - I was in the process of pasting the code into PL/SQL developer to format it so I could find the error, but then I just spotted the typo as I was getting ready to copy the code to the clipboard.  So I never got as far as formatting it :).